# How can I write a bash/zsh command to see the failure of the previous command

Tags: bash, sh, zsh

I have been running gradle using the command line. Since I am on a Mac I would like to have the terminal speak to tell me the gradle command failed or succeeded. So I wrote a command
sayStatus

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

VAR=$?
echo "Did I really succeed? $VAR"
if [[ "$VAR" -eq "0" ]]; then 
  say "success"
else
  say "failed"
fi
```

I run is as
./gradelw ... ; sayStatus

Every time it says Success even if the gradle command fails.
If I actually the code to the command line it works:

```
./gradlew ... ; var=$?; if [[ "$var" -eq "0" ]]; then; say success; else; say failed; fi
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong in the script that it can't see the return code of the previous command?

Comment: execute Gradle manually (from cli, of course) and then manually run echo $?
Does it match the expected behavior in provided exit codes?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `saySuccess` is run in a new shell process that does not have access to your current shell's `$?` variable.

Change it to a shell function that you can store in your `~/.bashrc`

```sh
sayStatus() {
  local VAR=$?
  echo "Did I really succeed? $VAR"
  if [[ "$VAR" -eq "0" ]]; then
    say "success"
  else
    say "failed"
  fi
}
```

And test with

```sh
bash -c 'exit 42'; sayStatus
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend wrapping the command around a function. It's clearer and it's easier to refactor the code - you don't have to check `$?` value and think about "och, what was the last command that was run?", just the wrapper is on the same line as the command, so you know what it will run:

```
run_and_say_status() {
    if "$@"; then 
      say "success"
    else
      say "failed"
      return 1
    fi
}
run_and_say_status ./gradlew

# you can re-use it, cause the `return 1` in the function above:
if ! run_and_say_status ./gradlew; then
    echo "Och no, it failed!"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

[`$?`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646526/what-is-is-it-a-variable) hold the return value of the last command.

Since you're calling your script **after** the `gradlew` script, `$?` isn't the result of the command you are expecting due to a new shell process.

I would recommend moving all the calls into a single script, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Call gradlew
./gradlew

# Check exit code
if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]; then 
  say "success"
else
  say "failed"
fi
```

Comment: No it doesn't. $0 holds the program name